# Returning the Indexes of an element that appears in a list of lists

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

```
list = [['2', '6', '1'], ['2', '6', '4', '3', '1', '5']]
```

indexes of where `"2"` appears should return

```
[0,0],[1,0]
```

using `[[i, bins.index('2')] for i, bins in enumerate(list) if '2' in bins]`
i only get back [0,0]

not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: I got back what you expected [[0, 0], [1, 0]]. How are you testing ?

Answer (score 0):

I get `[[0, 0], [1, 0]]` if I run your code! You should not call it `list` though, as it's a python method, just call it e.g. `list_` !

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't name your list "list". List is a python method. For me the code works, and returns the wanted values [[0, 0], [1, 0]], but I can imagine that redifining a python method might mess with things.